# Is there a way that OpenMP can operate on Qt spanwed threads?

Tags: macos, qt, gcc, crash, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize a number-crunching part of an application to make use of a quad-core architecture using OpenMP and GCC 4.2 on Mac OS 10.5. But what I think the problem is that this application uses Qt for the GUI and I'm trying to fork the worker threads on a secondary thread created by Qt which causes the program to crash - but of this I'm not sure.

I'm seriously on the dark here since it's my first time working with either Qt or OpenMP, (or C++ for that matter). Any sort of guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the part using OpenMP work
   standalone, i.e. when not running in
   a Qt thread?
2. Can you maybe tackle your problem
   using [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/threads-qtconcurrent.html) or some
   other solution from the [thread
   support in Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/threads.html)?
3. In any case, can you provide some of
   your code for illustration? Usually
   that makes matters a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this does not work. I think it even was reported as a bug in Qt and gcc - if I remember correctly. It was reported several times (e.g. [here](http://www.archivum.info/qt-interest@trolltech.com/2010-01/01480/Re:-(Qt-interest)-(1-2-OT)-ImageMagick-OpenMP-and-QThread-(Mac-OS-X).html)). It works with some gcc/Qt combinations at least on linux.

Comment: Commenting myself here. Using the as of today latest macports gcc build (gcc version 4.5.1), the problem is resolved. Having openmp threads started from within a worker QThread works like it should.