# How a recent version of GCC (4.6) could be used together with Qt under Mac OS?

Tags: qt, macos, gcc, openmp

My problem is related to the one discussed here:

[Is there a way that OpenMP can operate on Qt spanwed threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106455/is-there-a-way-that-openmp-can-operate-on-qt-spanwed-threads/6252380#6252380)

Upon trying to run my Qt-based program under Mac OS that has an OpenMP clause in a secondary thread, it crashed.  After browsing through the web, now I understand that it is caused by a bug in the rather old version (4.2) of gcc supplied by Apple.

Then I downloaded the latest 4.6 version of gcc from http://hpc.sourceforge.net and tried to compile the project, but I got the following errors from g++ compiler:

unrecognized option ‘-arch’
unrecognized option ‘-Xarch_x86_64’

I learned that this is because these are options, which can be only interpreted by the custom-configured Apple-gcc compiler, but not by standard gcc.

Could anybody please help me  could I overcome this issue and configure g++ 4.6 to use with Qt in order to get a bug-free OpenMP support? I admit that I'm a newbie under Mac OS platform with regard to compilers and programming and would like to port my code from Visual Studio-Qt environment.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give us a little more, like your configure command... A few more lines of the error?

Comment: Well, that's nearly all what I got, the 2 unrecognized option errors and another one: 'x86-64' No such file or directory. This is upon trying to compile the project.

I did not use 'configure', just simply created a profile under Build Settings in Qt Creator to use GCC 4.6.  With the Apple-GCC compiler it compiles fine.

Do I need to compile Qt itself by GCC 4.6?

Comment: -arch should be in the vanilla GCC 4.6 for darwin, it is documented. as for the error, have you tried to remove the arch option from the qt build settings, the compiler should infer the correct value.

Comment: Those errors look like errors from several different parts of the compilation pipeline. Without the actual text from the transcript, including the binary logging the error and the commandline it's logging the error in response to, it will be hard for anyone to help you further. Please provide appropriate excerpts from the transcript in-line in your question. Posting the entire transcript, including your environment, directory layout, and any configuration files somewhere off-site where interested readers could view them also couldn't hurt, but might be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't afraid of messing with your Qt installation, then change the QMAKE_CFLAGS_X86_64 entry in ~/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/mkspecs/common/g++-macx.conf.

Replace  ‘-Xarch_x86_64’ with ‘-arch x86_64’.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your non-Apple gcc v4.6 and compile a binary for each architecture you want to build (use --target=${ARCH} should be fine for i386 and x86_64). Then once you have a binary for each of the architectures use lipo like so:
`lipo -create -arch i386 binary_32bit -arch x86_64 binary_64bit -output binary_universal`
This will create a fat binary (aka universal binary) named binary_universal from binary_32bit and binary_64bit.

Or you could use clang/llvm instead of gcc, which probably won't have the bug you described and (if supplied via Apple's developer tools) should be able to compile universal binaries directly.

Comment: The problem here is that clang and llvm-gcc don't support

Comment: I read somewhere that llvm-gcc supported OpenMP (wouldn't know as I don't use it), probably in the [release notes](http://llvm.org/releases/2.4/docs/ReleaseNotes.html) somewhere. Sorry for the slight miss information.

Comment: Wow, sorry, didn't mean to halfway post that comment.  It does, but it's also based on GCC 4.2 so it'll probably have the same bugs.  Dragonegg might do it, but since it uses the FSF GCC it may have the same issues.

Comment: There is defiantly a chance it has the bug, however since llvm does the code generation and gcc 4.2 is only used for front-end compiling I would expect bugs to be less of an issue. Also, I fixed a typo in my post (lip to lipo).

Answer (score 0):

You should run qmake woth corresponding -spec option, for example, to use gcc46 on freebsd it is needed to run qmake so:
qmake --spec=freebsd-g++46

Answer (score 0):

Lipo can indeed be used to put multiple object files together into a "fat" object file, in fact it turns out this is just what apple's compiler does.  Their GCC compiler is actually a driver that maps various architectures to the appropriate compiler for the architecture and then mashes the objects together using lipo.

see: http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-dev/2011-September/016210.html

Here is the source file for that driver:

http://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5666.3/driverdriver.c

All one needs to do to get a new version of GCC to honor the -arch flag is to modify this driver and get it to point to a script wrapper for your version of gcc that adds the appropriate flags for the given architecture and then passes all the rest of the arguments.  Something like this:

#!/bin/sh

/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.6 -m32 $@

and

#!/bin/sh

/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.6 -m64 $@

Here is a link that talks about how to do it, and provides a cmake project to easily get the macports version of GCC fixed up and supporting the -arch flag for the two intel architectures:

http://thecoderslife.blogspot.com/2015/07/building-with-gcc-46-and-xcode-4.html