# QT Creator adds -Xarch

Tags: macos, qt-creator, gcc4.8

I was using the QT Creator with an old GCC, now i updated to the 4.8 version.
But the QT Creator adds a -Xarch_x86_64 option, the GCC 4.8 tells me

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Xarch_x86_64'
```

Is there a way to remove this options?
I tried to use

```
CONFIG -= x86_64 ppc64 x86 ppc 64 arch_x86_64 -arch -Xarch_x86_64
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -v
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= x86_64 ppc64 x86 ppc 64 arch_x86_64 -arch -Xarch_x86_64
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
QMAKE_LFLAGS -= x86_64 ppc64 x86 ppc 64 arch_x86_64 -arch -Xarch_x86_64
```

But so far nothing happens.

Note: i'm using the last QT Creator version, with a GCC downloaded using Port and i changed the compiler on the kit.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed all the references using.

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_PPC_64     -= -arch ppc64 -Xarch_ppc64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS_PPC_64  -= -arch ppc64 -Xarch_ppc64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
QMAKE_CFLAGS_X86_64     -= -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS_X86_64  -= -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_PPC_64   -= -arch ppc64 -Xarch_ppc64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_X86_64   -= -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
QMAKE_LFLAGS_PPC_64     -= -arch ppc64 -Xarch_ppc64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
QMAKE_LFLAGS_X86_64     -= -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
```

It solved my problem

Comment: Worked for me!  Consider accepting this answer, it might help others find the post.

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: g++-mp-4.8. Use port to download it. If you need to compile the libstdcxx dont forget to update your XCode

Comment: I have installed gcc48 with brew but if I print `gcc` or `g++` in the terminal it does not find the binary.. i have to manually make a softlink.. but it is giving me the error `error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory`

Comment: You can force to use it using QMAKE_CXX        = /path/to/g++-mp-4.8

Comment: if you do a g++ -v it returns the correct version? I don't know a lot about brew. But do not do a softlink, instead put your new g++ location in your path. It can't find because your OS don't know where the other commands are.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to resolve this problem is to edit the file for the compiler configuration for the specific qt version and the specific target build.

See [this post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/1186/opencv-on-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion/?answer=1533#post-id-1533).

In my case this conf file is:

```
/usr/local/Qt4.8/mkspecs/common/g++-macx.conf
```

And the changes are:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_X86_64 += -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
QMAKE_CFLAGS_PPC_64 += -Xarch_ppc64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
```

to

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_X86_64 += -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
QMAKE_CFLAGS_PPC_64 += -Xarch_ppc64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
```

Please see the [linked](http://answers.opencv.org/question/1186/opencv-on-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion/?answer=1533#post-id-1533) post from natoferreira in the Q&A of opencv website. Also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12261728/433685) mention this file.

Please add a comment if you know other information about this configuration file for Qt and GCC.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using GCC installed via MacPorts (tested several versions up to gcc5). The solution for me was using `g++` supplied with the XCode command line tools. I uninstalled all MacPorts GCC versions. Below version details of the `g++` command that worked.

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```