# Unrecognized command line option '-Xarch_x86_64' in PyQt4 installation on mac

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I made sure to try installing PyQt4 on mac in many different ways, but I always get the error above.
My attempts have in common installing Python 3.4 from the official website installer, then installing Qt4 from [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.6/) and finally installing SIP from the package available in the Riverbanks website.

I've already tried to install PyQt4 by running the configure-ng.py, the configure.py without options and configure.py with a reasonable number of different combinations (by empiric/hopelessness purposes), but I know the "pattern" for the options would be "-q" option to indicate the qmake path, "-d" option to the python path and "--use-arch x86_64" to indicate, I guess, the machine architecture (I made sure to use "uname -a", something like that, to check if I really should use "x86_64"). Simply nothing worked!

After all that trouble, I have tried to install SIP and PyQt4 on the Python 2.7 and lastly I've tried to use Homebrew to install all that stuff. Again it doesn't worked.

Someone has idea what could fix the problem? (Unfortunately I have the possibility to work with a mac just once a week, then I cannot test your solutions immediately.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look a little on what Google has to say, there are several references to that problem. I see you are from Brasil so maybe this is your problem:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/291
(which refers to: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/224

Also:

- https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/682
- https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/291
- https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CDcQFjAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftrac.macports.org%2Fticket%2F22924&ei=LCMpVYbtOIOYNv7NgPAO&usg=AFQjCNH7wcogTMUJHKR7NlOSIOWHWGzsIA&bvm=bv.90491159,d.eXY&cad=rja

Comment: In fact I took a look, but I really expected that the answer was in the PyQt4 documentation. Thank you very much anyway. I'll try use these references to solve my problem next week.

Comment: As I understand it, this was somehow a bug - part of the software was installed without support for international characters. So it would not be in the manual...

Comment: Well, a second attempt using homebrew was sufficient to let everything working well. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using GCC installed via MacPorts (tested several versions up to gcc5). The solution for me was using g++ supplied with the XCode command line tools. I uninstalled all MacPorts GCC versions. Below version details of the g++ command that worked.

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

A similar question was asked here: [QT Creator adds -Xarch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16701355/3922554)